# Trying to do input validation for rps game

Tags: python-3.x, input

I'm making an rps game on python 3.6 and can't seem to figure out how to do input validation for my two player game function module. Whenever I run the program and select two player game and enter a number less than 1 or more than 4, it just asks if I want to play again.

```
   def twoPlayerGame():
        player1 = False
        player2 = 0
        player1Win = 0
        player2Win = 0
        tie_ = 0

        #prompting for weapon choice
        while player1 == False:
            weaponMenu()
            player1 = int(input("Player 1, please make a selection.\t"))
            player2 = int(input("Player 2, please make a selection.\t"))

            while player1 or player2 not in range(1,4):
                print ("Invalid data entered, try again.")
                weaponMenu()
                player1 = int(input("Player 1, please make a selection.\t"))
                player2 = int(input("Player 2, please make a selection.\t"))

            #redirects to main
            while player1 == 4 or player2 == 4:
                main()

            if player1 == player2:
                print("It's a tie!\n")
                tie_ = tie_ + 1
            elif player1 == 1:
                if player2 == 2:
                    print("Paper covers rock! Player 2 won!\n")
                    player2Win = player2Win + 1
                else:
                    print("Rock smashes scissors! Player 1 won!\n")
                    player1Win = player1Win + 1
            elif player1 == 2:
                if player2 == 3:
                    print("Scissors cuts paper! Player 2 won!\n")
                    player2Win = player2Win + 1
                else:
                    print("Paper covers rock! Player 1 won!\n")
                    player1Win = player1Win + 1
            elif player1 == 3:
                if player2 == 1:
                    print("Rock smashes scissors! Player 2 won!\n")
                    player2Win = player2Win + 1
                else:
                    print("Scissors cuts paper! Player 2 won!\n")
                    p1ayer2Win = player2Win + 1


            #ask user if they want to play again
            again = input("Play again? Enter yes or no.\n")
            again = again.lower()
            #display scores
            print("Ties:\t", tie_)
            print("Player 1 wins:\t", player1Win)
            print("Player 2 wins:\t", player2Win)

            #if yes, player still playing
            #if no, redirect to main
            if again=="yes":
                player1 = False
            else:
                player1 = True
                main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with this line:

```
 while player1 or player2 not in range(1,4):
```

Whatever you put on each side of `or` should usually be a true or false value. Putting `player1` on the left side, while acceptable to the Python interpreter, is incorrect here because what you want to do is check if it's in range. On the right side, `player2 not in range(1,4)` is an actual true/false value, so that's fine.

So change the thing on the left to `player1 not in range(1,4)`, and the function works fine:

```
while player1 not in range(1,4) or player2 not in range(1,4):
```